# How to remove rows that have 3 word or less in dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe

Because I want to remove ambiguity when I train the data. I want to clean it well. So how can I remove all rows that contain 3 words or less in python?

Comment: Sample dataframe? Any code you've tried so far?

Comment: And I would love to see a correct question here... More seriously without some sample data how can we guess what your dataframe looks like? You are supposed to provide a [mcve] in the question so that we can try our solutions on something close enough to your data. Without it we really cannot help.

Comment: Was your problem solved? Please let know, and if possible, please update the question with some examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hello World!** This will be my first contribution ever to SO :-)

Let's create some **data**:

```
data = { 'Source':['Hello all Im Happy','Its a lie, dont trust him','Oops','foo','bar']}
df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['Source'])
```

My approach is very straight forward, simple  and little "brute" and inefficient,howver I ran this in a large dataframe (1013952 rows) and the time was fairly acceptable. 
let's find the indices of the data frame where there are more than n tokens:

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize


def get_indices(df,col,n): 
"""
Get the indices of dataframe where exist more than n tokens in a specific column

Parameters:

   df(pandas dataframe)
   n(int): threshold value for minimum words
   col(string): column name 

"""      


tmp = []
for i in range(len(df)):#df.iterrows() wasnt working for me
    if len(word_tokenize(df[col][i])) < n:
        tmp.append(i)
return tmp
```

Next we just need to call the function and drop the rows and said indices:

```
tmp = get_indices(df)
df_clean = df.drop(tmp)
```

Best!

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"mycolumn": ["", " ", "test string", "test string 1", "test string 2 2"]})
df = df.loc[df["mycolumn"].str.count(" ") >= 2]
```

You should never loop over a dataframe, always use vectorized operations.